# issues with creating cross region read replica cluster for RDS aurora using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

> **UPDATE: issue #2 is actually not terraform issue..issue was with AWS..i fixed that..code works fine..only thing left now is issue #1
> with the AZs issue**

i have a **RDS aurora cluster** with 1 instance in it in `us-east-1` and want to create a **cross region read replica RDS aurora cluster** with 1 instance in it in `us-west-2`

there are like 2 issues am having when trying to create a cross region read replica from an RDS aurora cluster using terrform

here is my main.tf file

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.aws_region}"

}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rds-aurora" {
  name       = "${var.name}-${var.aws_region}"
  subnet_ids = ["${split(",",lookup(var.subnet_ids, "${var.aws_region}"))}"]
  tags {
    Name            = "${var.name}-${var.env}-${var.aws_region}"
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "rds-aurora-cluster-pg" {
  name        = "${var.name}-cluster-pg-${var.aws_region}"
  family      = "aurora5.6"
  description = "${var.name} cluster parameter group"
  parameter {
    name  = "secure_auth"
    value = "1"
  }
  parameter {
    name  = "binlog_format"
    value = "MIXED"
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }
  tags {
    Name            = "${var.name}-${var.env}-${var.aws_region}"
  }
  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }  
}

resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "rds-aurora-pg" {
  name   = "${var.name}-pg-${var.aws_region}"
  family = "aurora5.6"
  description = "${var.name} parameter group"
  parameter {
    name  = "secure_auth"
    value = "1"
  }
  tags {
    Name            = "${var.name}-${var.env}-${var.aws_region}"
  }
  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds-aurora" {
  cluster_identifier      = "${var.name}"
  availability_zones      = ["${lookup(var.availability_zones, var.aws_region)}"]  
  skip_final_snapshot = "true"
  backup_retention_period = "${var.rds_backup}"
  preferred_backup_window = "09:00-09:30"
  preferred_maintenance_window = "mon:06:00-mon:06:30"
  apply_immediately = "true"
  engine_mode       = "provisioned"
  deletion_protection = "false"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${split(",",lookup(var.security_groups, var.aws_region))}"]
  storage_encrypted = "true"
  db_subnet_group_name = "${aws_db_subnet_group.rds-aurora.name}"
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "${aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.rds-aurora-cluster-pg.name}"
  kms_key_id = "${var.kms_key_id}"
  replication_source_identifier = "${var.replication_source_identifier}${var.name}"
  source_region = "${var.source_region}"
  tags {
    Name            = "${var.name}-${var.env}-${var.aws_region}"
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "rds-aurora" {
  count              = "${var.rds_count}"
  identifier         = "${var.name}-${count.index}"
  engine = "aurora"
  db_subnet_group_name = "${aws_db_subnet_group.rds-aurora.name}"
  db_parameter_group_name = "${aws_db_parameter_group.rds-aurora-pg.name}"
  instance_class     = "${var.instance_class}"
  cluster_identifier = "${aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora.cluster_identifier}"
  tags {
    Name            = "${var.name}-${var.env}-${var.aws_region}"
  }
}
```

and here are the issues am facing

## 1. first issue is am getting this error

```
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: error creating RDS cluster: InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault: Availability zone '[us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c]' is unavailable in this region, please choose another zone set.
```

and those availability zones do exist and i believe i have entered the values in the proper way
here is how terraform got the values for the availabiity zones

```
...
availability_zones.2635104823:     "" => "us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c"
...
```

which is correct format and the AZs exist like i said..i have created RDS from scratch and same format works but now trying to create a cross region read replica is only when i get the error that the AZs dont exist

now i was able to move forward to next issue by adding just 1 AZ to get past this stage..but the issue still exists and i will like to fix that as well

n ow next is issue #2 below...the main issue

## 2. now the major error is the bug i believe exist with creating cross region read replica for RDS aurora with terraform

the terrform apply gets stuck when creating the rds cluster and it never completes...it runs here for like more than 2 hours before a timeout kicks in..and one thing i noticed is when i check the AWS dashboard i can see the RDS cluster is created but there is no RDS instance under it but terrform keeps runing the creation of the RDS cluster forever

```
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (10s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (20s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (30s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (40s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (50s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (1m0s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (1m10s elapsed)
...
...
...
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (1h59m40s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (1h59m50s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (2h0m0s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (2h0m10s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (2h0m20s elapsed)
aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: Still creating... (2h0m30s elapsed)
```

so i think there is a bug where terrafrom does not know when the RDS cluster is created so it can create the RDS instance under it as specified in the main.tf file above

anyone willing to help with these 2 issues?

Comment: It's still not clear if you are trying to create a read replica cluster or if you are trying to create just a read replica instance. If you are attempting to create a read replica cluster then using replication_source_identifier makes sense. 

I can't see your variable definitions for aws_region or source_region but are they in different regions and do you have the correct AZ's for each region also defined in your variables?

Comment: did you see this line under `aws_rds_cluster` resource
`replication_source_identifier = "${var.replication_source_identifier}${var.name}"`?

that is where i am referencing a remote rds cluster to create the read replica from

Comment: I have the exact same issue as num 2. Figured it out?

Comment: @jetru can you please share your solution?

Comment: Don't have a solution yet. :(

Comment: any updates on issue #2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are creating read replica cluster instead of read replica instance, are you specifying a db instance or a cluster as source? You should be setting the source as a db_instance in the cluster, not the source cluster. Ideally a read replica if you are using a multi AZ HA source.

One thing to keep in mind, since I dont know your environment and have to shoot from the hip, if you using a single host cluster. Don't bother using a cluster. Just use a single db instance. It's simpler and relatively the same

Comment: the source db is a RDS aurora cluster with 1 DB instance..so are you saying i should use the DB instance as source DB instead of the DB cluster?

Comment: ok here is what am trying to do...i have an RDS aurora cluster with i writer RDS aurora instance in us-east-1 region and want to create a read replica RDS aurora cluster in us-west-2 from the cluster in us-east-1..that is what am trying to do...i just changed the source DB to instance instead of cluster and got error..saying `aws_rds_cluster.rds-aurora: error creating RDS cluster: DBClusterNotFoundFault: Source cluster rds-aurora-0 not found in region us-east-1` so i have explained what am trying to do so know hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

What I am saying is that is difficult to see what you are doing based on the TF code you have provided. Where is the source cluster TF code and your variable definitions?